# appium settings app preventing my application to run

Tags: mock-location

Please find below attachment[mainerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT41B.png)

Error: "you have an unauthorized fake location app in your mobile phone uninstall appium settings to continue appium error"

I have uninstalled the app, but when I run my code again appium settings app is auto-installing. Please help me with this.

Comment: What is your programming issue?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts, that was the error, it's blocking my way in performing the further task. At code level can we handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Though APPIUM has the desired capabilities to handle this issue for only a real device, it was not working for me.

For more info on APPIUM desired capabilities, please find the link below
https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/

**mockLocationApp** - is the desired capabilities.

**- Description:**

This sets the package identifier of the app, which is used as a system mock location provider since Appium 1.18.0+. This capability has no effect on emulators. If the value is set to null or an empty string, then Appium will skip the mocked location provider setup procedure. Defaults to Appium Setting package identifier (io.appium.settings).

- **Values:**

e.g., null, io.appium.settings, example.your.app

I have checked with our developer, it was handled from the backend (code level).

Comment: How did you end up handling this? My app is blocking for this same reason and DC doesn't work...